# Conditional Formatting based on highest value and color red the new cell

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am very new to excel macro VBA I am trying put conditional formating that put colour red in Cell "AN" based on the target values present in cell "AC, AE, AG and AI" respectively these cells have values which differ each time and the highest values depending on the target given in corresponding cells if the target is more then these cells ("AC, AE, AG and AI") are highlighted in red.

Comment: No response yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cells "AC, AE, AG and AI" becomes red if values of them are exeeds of correspondents "expected" cells.
2. Theese are criterias to paint "AN" in red
3. Try to use condition formatting in "AN2" with formula such as:
   =OR($AC2>$AB2,$AE2>$AD2,$AG2>$AF2,$AI2>$AH2)

and red paint.